# Unpermitted parameter in Rails API nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api, accepts-nested-attributes

I'm trying to update an object using nested fields and am receiving an `Unpermitted parameters` error. The field that is causing the error is in itself a relation to another table within the nested table. Below are the specifics:

Doctor class

```
class Doctor < User
    has_many :professional_licenses, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :states, through: :professional_licenses
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :professional_licenses, allow_destroy: true
   ...
end
```

Professional License class

```
class ProfessionalLicense < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :state

  validates_presence_of :code
end
```

State class

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :iso_abbr, :name
end
```

Doctor controller

```
...
def update
  doctor = @current_user
  params[:doctor][:professional_licenses_attributes].each do |license, index|
    license[:state] = State.find_by_iso_abbr license[:state]
  end
  doctor.update_attributes(doctor_params)
  render json: doctor, status: :ok
end
...
def doctor_params
  params.require(:doctor).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, 
  :password_confirmation, professional_licenses_attributes: [:code, :state, :_destroy])
end
```

The call from the UI looks like this:

```
{
"doctor":{
    "first_name":"Doctor Postman",
    "professional_licenses_attributes": [
        {
            "code": "NY-1234",
            "state": "NY"
        },
        {
            "code": "MA-1234",
            "state": "MA"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

When I send the call, the record is being updated and the licenses created. However, the licenses get created with no state because the controller says `Unpermitted parameters: state`. I have tried different approaches but can't find the way to permit the state. Please help!

Comment: Could you inspect your `params` before and after `.each` cycle?

Comment: Which _unpermitted param_? Please show complete error/log.

Comment: @Gerry the error I get is `{"message":"undefined method `iso_abbr' for nil:NilClass"}`. the `iso_abbrr` is the State's abbreviation in that table. Here's the console output too https://gist.github.com/davidflores2/2818385e1f217456d6a2bac40e4b00d5

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk here are the params before and after: https://gist.github.com/davidflores2/6e5f73612b43a5df4e724fcc4927bd32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `code` parameter is expected to be a simple value such as integer or string. But you convert it into an object, which attributes also have to be added to the permitted list.

Try to pass `code_id` (integer) instead of `code` (object):

```
...
def update
  doctor = @current_user
  params[:doctor][:professional_licenses_attributes].each do |license|
    state = State.find_by_iso_abbr(license.delete(:state))
    license[:state_id] = state.id if state
  end
  doctor.update_attributes(doctor_params)
  render json: doctor, status: :ok
end
...
def doctor_params
  params.require(:doctor).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, 
  :password_confirmation, professional_licenses_attributes: [:code, :state_id, :_destroy])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. In this case, `:code` is a string so I can't pass the id. I have tried to pass just `:state` and the object and I also get the same error as when I do `:state_id`

Comment: You don't have to pass ID. You pass a string and calculate the ID, based on the string. You also should remove `:state` from `params` after you convert it to `state_id` (I missed this when answered). I updated the answer. Now `:state` is removed from `params` after it is converted into `state_id`

Comment: I made the change you suggested and get the same error: `"undefined method 'iso_abbr' for nil:NilClass"`  Here's a gist with the console output. Maybe you can see something I'm not. https://gist.github.com/davidflores2/ca334be415526fd1c03e874d973980c9

Comment: In the gist the code is wrong! You missed `license.delete(:state)` and  `if state` Copy it from here and use properly.